# Changing AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key field to NOT NULL prevents record insert with error 'no default value for field'

Tags: mysql, database-design

Simple test table (defined using MySQL Workbench 8.0 on Mac OSX Mojave):

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (
id int(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Field1 int(10),
Field2 varchar(100) );
```

Inserting a record without specifying id works fine (it is set to the next auto-increment value):

```
INSERT INTO Test1(Field1,Field2) VALUES (99,'def');
```

From an abundance of caution I decided to change the primary key to NOT NULL to prevent someone manually entering an id and duplicating an existing id:
    ALTER TABLE Test1 CHANGE id id int NOT NULL;

But now trying to insert a record, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO Test1(Field1,Field2) VALUES (100,'efg');
```

generates the error "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value".

And if I try to put set the field to NULL:

```
ALTER TABLE Test1 CHANGE 
id
id int(11) NULL;
```

I get the error "All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL".

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS PK implies UNIQUE NOT NULL. There can only be one PK. You can't declare it NULL. A column ALTER TABLE replaces an old declaration by the new one--so NULL replaced AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY so update leaving a column out did not get an auto value & it needed a DEFAULT to be declared. AUTO_INCREMENT does not imply NOT NULL (& can't have DEFAULT). This is all explained by the manual. Read the manual re syntax/functionality you are using. This question lacks research. Also a [mre] would read metadata after CHANGEs to confirm effects.

Comment: First of all, if I put "why does" at the beginning of the sentence and a question mark at the end, it would clearly be a question. Secondly, I agree that the details of the manual explain this, but it is not intuitive. Therefore I thought it worth sharing my experience for others. The problem is a very subtle interaction between characteristics of the field. It is not illogical (although wrong) to think that "NOT NULL" and "AUTO_INCREMENT" are independent characteristics of a field. On other databases (FileMaker for example), these characteristics are independent.

Comment: Reviewing the manual, I don't think things are as clear as you say: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be quite simple, set the field to AUTO_INCREMENT which implies NOT NULL:

```
ALTER TABLE Test1 CHANGE 
id
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Do not specify PRIMARY KEY because then you get a spurious error about "Multiple primary key defined".